# What is the syntax of the activate() function in pybrain package?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation, pybrain, feed-forward

I have a code which builds a [2,3,1] neural network with some values with full connection.

```
from pybrain.structure import FeedForwardNetwork, LinearLayer, SigmoidLayer, FullConnection
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork

n = FeedForwardNetwork()

inLayer = LinearLayer(2)
hiddenLayer = SigmoidLayer(3)
outLayer = LinearLayer(1)

n.addInputModule(inLayer)
n.addModule(hiddenLayer)
n.addOutputModule(outLayer)

in2hidden = FullConnection(inLayer, hiddenLayer)
hidden2out = FullConnection(hiddenLayer, outLayer)
n.addConnection(in2hidden)
n.addConnection(hidden2out)

print n.activate([1, 2])
```

This is the code. Its clear that activate() function takes a list as input.I cant understand what is the contents of the list.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  I just made the following change to the bottom of your code:

```
n.addConnection(in2hidden)
n.addConnection(hidden2out)
n.sortModules()
testactivate = n.activate([0.6, 0.6])
print testactivate
```

I get output like: [ 0.54307993]

The input to n.activate, in this case ([0.6, 0.6]), is the inputs to the input layer of your FeedForward network (which in this case takes two inputs).

Of course, your output will be different each time, as the initial weights (prior to any training) are going to be randomly assigned.